# Jenkins pipeline: write file in different directory than workspace

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I use this in my Jenkins pipeline:

```
def script = libraryResource 'tests/checks-test.sh'
file: 'script.sh', text: script
```

This will write a file `script.sh` in my workspace. Now I want that this file isn't in my workspace. (A bit like managed files which are in the `/tmp/` folder of jenkins.

How can I force my pipeline to write the file in the `/tmp` folder and not in my workspace?

Comment: What about `sh 'mv ...'`?

Comment: You could wrap the whole thing in a dir('/tmp') {...}?